# Runtime error in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get the row values of my listview control when it is clicked and I
want to display it in the textboxes. I found an article demonstrating this kind 
of scenario at http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=7597714. I tried
to use javascript to get the row values of my listview control and set it to my
textboxes to display using the format of the javascript code given on that article.
I need help fixing the runtime error on my javascript codes which pops-up an error window
and says **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected**, everytime you clicked any of
the rows. Here's my code below for your reference: Thanks in advance.

```
<script type ="text/javascript" >

    var row;
    var id,name,addr,age,natn,occ;

    function GetRow(rowval)
    {
        row = $(rowval).parent().parent(); // the runtime error hightlights on this line

        id = $("#id", row).text();
        name = $("#name", row).text();
        addr = $("#addr", row).text();
        age = $("#age", row).text();
        natn = $("#natn",row ).text();
        occ = $("#occ",row).text();

        row.addClass("highlightRow");

        $("#TextBox1").val(id);
        $("#TextBox2").val(name);
        $("#TextBox3").val(addr);
        $("#TextBox4").val(age);
        $("#TextBox5").val(natn);
        $("#TextBox6").val(occ);
    }

</script>
```

Source code from my listview control in the ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>

    <tr style="background-color:#E0FFFF; color: #333333;" >
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' style="cursor: pointer;" onclick = "return GetRow();" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="AddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="AgeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="NationalityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nationality") %>' />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="OccupationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Occupation") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>

</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: `rowval` is undefined when you don't define it in the html that's calling the `GetRow` method.

Comment: Are you add jquery script file ?

Comment: Do you use the same IDs multiple times? Avoid that (though it should not cause this error)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please guide me on how to define the rowval in the html? I'm just a little bit confuse since I contruct these codes based on the article on the link.

Comment: @Ramesh...I don't think I have a jquery script file because the article only use javascript but if it is necessary then pls guide me on ohe to do it.

Comment: @Bergi.. I don't think I use same multiple IDs.I declare it as variables

Comment: @Kevin.. Can you please guide me on how to define the rowval in the html?

Comment: GetRow is my javascript function and I call it when the row is clicked on the listview as what is being shown in the item template.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

Give your label `IDLabel` a CssClass.  Lets say `myLabel` for this example.  Then add the following code for the click event (you will no longer need `GetRow`):

```
$(".myLabel").click(function(){
    row = $(this).parent().parent();
    // all your other stuff from GetRow()
});
```

I noticed that you are referencing #TextBox1 in your jquery code.  You should note that if TextBox1 is an asp.net control this will not work for selecting that element since the element id that gets rendered is not TextBox1.

Comment: @Abe...I'm confused, where should I insert that code from my codes above.

Comment: $("#TextBox1").val(id); this code as what I understood from the article sets the value from the listview row to the textbox control.

Comment: Insert the code in your jquery `ready` event.  You don't show where your textbox control is defined so I can't say for sure, but I am almost positive that selector will not find anything.